# jQuery UI Slider reset animation

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, jquery-animate

Trying to create a slider that will **slide back to the beginning** if it isn't dragged all the way across... here is what doesn't work:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).slider('value') < 100) {
            $(this).slider('value', 0);
        }
    }   
});
```

The slider moves back, but instantly, no animation.

Comment: Wait, when you say animation, that involves more than just setting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery ui 1.8.18 you will have to call it asynchronously:

```
$("#slider").slider({
   animate: true,
   stop: function(event, ui) {
     if($(this).slider('value') < 100) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $("#slider").slider('value', 0);
      },1);
    }
  }   
});
```

Comment: try this modified version, have tested it with the latest version of  jquery ui

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.value < 100) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#slider").slider("value", 0);
            }, 100);
        }
    }   
});
```

This fiddle shows an example too: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisabrams/2xkvy/1/

Comment: what's the difference between ui.value and $(this).slider('value')

Comment: In this case they are both the same. jQuery UI recommends using the ui object when possible to avoid scope issues. Also the answers were not so similar earlier..